# Why is my JSON not working for my sublime text settings?

Tags: json, sublimetext3

I do not code in JSON and I'm trying to configure some settings for Terminus on Sublime Text 3. Why isn't my code working? I suspect it has something to do with the colons because they appear to be a different color than on the README page. Thanks in advance!

```
[
    "default_config": {
        "linux": null,
        "osx": "PowerShell",
        "windows": null
    },

    "preserve_keys" : [
        "ctrl+k",
        "ctrl+p",
        "ctrl+z",
        "ctrl+c",
        "ctrl+v",
        "ctrl+x"
    ],

    "theme": "default"
]
```

Comment: I suspect the outermost `[ ]` characters should be `{ }` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `[ ]` with `{ }` like that:

```json
{
    "default_config": {
        "linux": null,
        "osx": "PowerShell",
        "windows": null
    },

    "preserve_keys" : [
        "ctrl+k",
        "ctrl+p",
        "ctrl+z",
        "ctrl+c",
        "ctrl+v",
        "ctrl+x"
    ],

    "theme": "default"
}
```

If you want to store data using `key` `value`, you have to use `{ }`. If you want to store data in json as an array, you have to use `[ ]`. This is the difference which made you an error.

---

Here's a good tutorial that you can use: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-json

It's all preety simple

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed it. I'll take a look at the tutorial because I'm basically illiterate in JSON and I should learn.